# Stopping the movement in the CarouFredSel

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, carousel, caroufredsel

I'm looking for an help on changing an option in the `CarouFredSel` plugin that I've found in the Avada Wordpress Theme. This plugin seems to be integrated and it is not something I can activate or deactivate.

I want that the carousel stops with the last image, on their website they say to edit and set the variable `circular` to **false**, but they don't say where. I did this change in `main.js`, `jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.0.js`, `jquery.carouFredSel.js` changing the default global variable but probably somewhere in Avada theme they are overriding it.

Can somebody help me on this "easy" thing? The Avada theme doesn't give support, and the support page of the plugin doesn't work.

Here the link for the configuration: [theme-fusion.com/knowledgebase/how-to-customize-the-carousel](http://theme-fusion.com/knowledgebase/how-to-customize-the-carousel) I'm using it inserting an "Image Carousel" element into the Wordpress page, directly through the user-friendly interface. I can set some variables but not the one about stopping.

This is his Wordpress code in the page: `[images picture_size="fixed" hover_type="none" autoplay="no" columns="4" column_spacing="2" scroll_items="2" show_nav="yes" mouse_scroll="no" border="no" lightbox="no" class="" id=""]`

Comment: Can you provide a link to the plugin? Also, how is that component currently integrated in your page?

Comment: Please put that in the question, not as a comment.